# Sorting of Columns of ColVis in Datatable jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using Datatable jQuery in View page to show data. I'm using the following code:

```
$('#tblAssodetails').dataTable({
"bFilter": false,
"bInfo": true,
"sScrollY": "300px", 
"sScrollX": "690px",                      
"bScrollCollapse": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"sDom": 'C<"clear">lfrtip'     ,           
"aoColumnDefs": [{"bVisible": false, "aTargets": [9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32]         });
```

I want to highlight 'Show/Hide columns' label using background color and the `Columnnames` in this label in sorted order. How can i do this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

CSS to change button backgrounds:

```
/* Buttons inside colvis drop down */
.ColVis_collection button:hover {
    background-color: #000000;
}
.ColVis_collection button:focus {
    background-color: #000000;
}
div.ColVis_collection button {
    background-color: #000000;
}

/* ColVis master button (opens drop down) */
.ColVis_MasterButton {
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

These are CSS styles pre-defined in your colvis.css file. You can go inside there and change them or you can overwrite them by calling them after you've called the colvis.css stylesheet.

You seem gung-ho on doing this with jQuery. It is possible to modify CSS using jQuery but *please note* all you'd be doing is telling jQuery to go modify your CSS in a case where it would have been better to write it correctly with CSS from the source:

```
// Example:
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.ColVis_collection button').css('background-color', '#000000' );
});
```

Comment: Column names are notoriously difficult to re-order in ColVis because it would require a major api extension in your native datatable init page. 

It's not possible to set up reording with .sort() from inside ColVis.js file because that file knows nothing about the column titles or how many of them there will be.

Maybe would work if you set-up an intermediate file as interface and passed values into colvis that way.